# Should I set stdout and stdin to be unbuffered in C?

Tags: c, buffer, stdout, stdin

Because of `stdin` and `stdout` buffering sometimes `printf`, `scanf` and `getchar` are not executed. I usually flush output buffer using `fflush(stdout)` but code can become very unreadable because of that. If I set `stdin` and `stdout` unbuffered using `setbuf(stdin, NULL)` and `setbuf(stdout, NULL)` will I make my program perform better or worse?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Making `stdin` or `stdout` completely unbuffered can make your program perform worse if it handles large quantities of input / output from and to files. Most I/O requests will be broken down as system calls on a byte by byte basis.

Note that buffering does not cause `printf`, `scanf` and `getchar` to not be executed: `printf` output to the final destination can just be delayed, so the input operation via `scanf` or `getchar` may occur without a prompt.

Note also that setting intput as unbuffered may not be effective from the terminal because the terminal itself performs its own buffering controlled via `stty` or `ioctl`.

Most C libraries have a hack that causes `stdout` to be flushed when reading from `stdin` requires getting data from the system, but this behavior is not specified in the C Standard, so some libraries do not implement it.  It is safe to add calls to `fflush(stdout);` before input operations, and after transitory messages such as progress meters.  For most purposes, it is best to let the C startup determine the appropriate buffering strategy depending upon the type of system handle associated with the `stdin` and `stdout` streams.  The common default is line buffered for devices and fully buffered with a size of `BUFSIZ` for files.

To get an idea of the potential performance hit, compile this naive `ccat` program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int c, size;

    if (argc > 1) {
        if (!strcmp(argv[1], "BUFSIZ"))
            size = BUFSIZ;
        else
            size = strtol(argv[1], NULL, 0);

        if (size == 0) {
            /* make stdin and stdout unbuffered */
            setvbuf(stdin, NULL, _IONBF, 0);
            setvbuf(stdout, NULL, _IONBF, 0);
        } else
        if (size > 0) {
            /* make stdin and stdout fully buffered */
            setvbuf(stdin, NULL, _IOFBF, size);
            setvbuf(stdout, NULL, _IOFBF, size);
        } else {
            /* make stdin and stdout line buffered */
            setvbuf(stdin, NULL, _IOLBF, -size);
            setvbuf(stdout, NULL, _IOLBF, -size);
        }
    }
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
        putchar(c);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Time program execution copying a large file several times to minimize file caching side effects.

On a Debian linux box I get these timings for a 3.8MB text file:

```
chqrlie@linux:~/dev/stackoverflow$ time wc w
 396684  396684 3755392 w
real    0m0.072s
user    0m0.068s
sys     0m0.000s

chqrlie@linux:~/dev/stackoverflow$ time cat < w > ww
real    0m0.008s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.004s

chqrlie@linux:~/dev/stackoverflow$ time ./ccat < w > ww
real    0m0.060s
user    0m0.056s
sys     0m0.000s

chqrlie@linux:~/dev/stackoverflow$ time ./ccat 0x100000 < w > ww
real    0m0.060s
user    0m0.058s
sys     0m0.000s

chqrlie@linux:~/dev/stackoverflow$ time ./ccat 0 < w > ww
real    0m5.326s
user    0m0.632s
sys     0m4.684s

chqrlie@linux:~/dev/stackoverflow$ time ./ccat -0x1000 < w > ww
real    0m0.533s
user    0m0.104s
sys     0m0.428s
```

As you can see:

- setting `stdin` and `stdout` to unbuffered causes the program to slow down by a factor of almost **100**,
- using line buffering slows down by a factor of **10** (because lines are short, 9 to 10 bytes on average)
- using a larger buffer does not show any improvement, the timing difference is not significant,
- the naive implementation is quite fast, but the real `cat` utility uses faster APIs for **6** times faster execution times.

As a conclusion: do not set `stdin` and `stdout` to unbuffered, it will impact performance significantly for even moderately large files.