# Why parent is not able to read stdin after a fork?

Tags: c, fork, stdin

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int main(){
    char buf[10];

    pid_t pid = fork();

    if (pid < 0){
        printf("error fork\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    if (pid == 0){
        fgets(buf,5,stdin);
        printf("Child : %s\n",buf);
        
    }
    else{
        wait(NULL);
        char* r = fgets(buf,5,stdin);
        if (r == NULL){
            printf("Parent : eof = %i\n",feof(stdin));
        }
        else {
            printf("Parent : %s\n",buf);
        }
        
    }
    return 0;
}
```

My program is very simple : a process is forked; the child process reads 4 characters from *stdin* and when it finishes, the parent process reads 4 characters from *stdin*.

Normally, if I write characters in *stdin* (before the fork) the child process should read the first 4 characters and then the parent process should read the next 4 characters. It seems quit logical as *fork()* duplicates the parent process, including the file descriptors and opened files.

But, when I execute
`echo 'aaaaaaaaa' | ./my_program`
I get
`Child : aaaa Parent : eof = 1`

It seems that *stdin* has been emptied by the child process when it finished.
I having hard time explaining this behavior.

Can you help me ? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Standard input is *usually* ([Is stdout line buffered, unbuffered or indeterminate by default?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3723795/6367213)) *line buffered* by default. Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34806727/6367213) to see what exactly this entails.

If you want your program to work as expected, explicitly set your standard input to be *unbuffered* (before the `fork()` call). This can be done like so:

```
setbuf(stdin, NULL);
```

Also see [Should I set stdout and stdin to be unbuffered in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35239938/6367213) for more  implications of setting `stdin` to be unbuffered.

Answer (score -3):

Try comment out after "else{"

```
//wait(NULL);
```

Comment: Removing the wait from the parent would not change the fact that the stream is buffered, so whichever process performs its `fgets` first is likely to get the entire line as it fills its buffer, starving the other process of input.

Comment: But at me with commented "wait(NULL)" parent prints "aaaaa".

Comment: @PeterIrich That's true. But then the child doesn't print anything.

Comment: There is my output when "wait(NULL)" is commented:
peter@peter1955:~/Documents> echo "aaaaaaa" | ./zzz_fork.elf 
Parent : aaaa
Child :

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).